# Quando executo o código fora do IDLE (PYTHON 3.7) não aparece a janela criada de Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, .exe, pyinstaller

Sou iniciante e tava estudando Tkinter e desenvolvi este código, dentro do IDLE ele funciona perfeitamente, porém com avançar eu transformei-o em executável mas não roda, mesmo dentro do cmd não roda. A caixa do tkinter não aparece. Alguem pode me dizer o que está errado?

Programa:

```
    from tkinter import *
from Usuarios import Usuarios


class Application:

    def __init__ (self, master):     
        self.fontp = ('Arial', '12')

        self.c1 = master

        Label(self.c1, text='Dados financeiros'
              , font=('Arial', '12', 'bold')).grid (column=2, row=1, pady=5)

        Label(self.c1, text='Nome: ', font=self.fontp, width=15).grid(column=1, row=2, pady=9)
        self.nome = Entry(self.c1, width=23)
        self.nome.grid(column=2, row=2)
        self.nome.focus_force() # Para o foco começar neste campo        
        self.busca = Button(self.c1, text='Buscar',font=self.fontp, width = 8)
        self.busca.grid(column=3, row=2, padx=9)
        root.bind('<Return>', self.buscanome)#enter para buscar
        self.busca.bind('<Any-Button>', self.buscanome)


        self.salario = Label(self.c1, text='Salario fixo: ', font=self.fontp, width=15)
        self.salario.grid(column=1, row=3, pady=5)
        self.salario1 = Entry(self.c1, width=23)
        self.salario1.grid(column=2, row=3)


        self.gastof = Label(self.c1, text='Gasto fixo Mensal: ', font=self.fontp, width=15)
        self.gastof.grid(column=1, row=4, pady=5)
        self.gastof1 = Entry(self.c1, width=23)
        self.gastof1.grid(column=2, row=4)


        self.gasto = Label(self.c1, text='Gasto: ', font=self.fontp, width=15)
        self.gasto.grid(column=1, row=5, pady=9)
        self.gasto1 = Entry(self.c1, width=23, state ='disabled')
        self.gasto1.grid(column=2, row=5)
        self.att = Button(self.c1, text='Adicionar',font=self.fontp, width = 8)
        self.att.grid(column=3, row= 5, padx=9)
        self.att['command'] = self.attgasto


        self.gastot = Label(self.c1, text='Gasto Total: ', font=self.fontp, width=15)
        self.gastot.grid(column=1, row=6, pady=5)
        self.gastot1 = Entry(self.c1, width=23, state ='disabled')
        self.gastot1.grid(column=2, row=6)


        self.gastop = Label(self.c1, text='Gasto previsto \nmensal: ', font=self.fontp, width=15)
        self.gastop.grid(column=1, row=7, pady=5)
        self.gastop1 = Entry(self.c1, width=23)
        self.gastop1.grid(column=2, row=7)


        self.ormt = Label(self.c1, text='', font=('Arial', '10'), width=20)
        self.ormt.grid(column=2, row=8, pady=5)


        self.cadastro = Button(self.c1, text='Cadastrar \nnovo usuário',font=self.fontp, width=12)
        self.cadastro['command'] = self.cadastrar
        self.cadastro.grid(column=1, row=9, columnspan=2, pady=5)

        self.attm = Button(self.c1, text='Atualização \nmensal',font=self.fontp, width=12)
        self.attm['command'] = self.atualizarmensal
        self.attm.grid(column=2, row=9, columnspan=2)



    def buscanome (self,event):
        user = Usuarios()

        nomeb = self.nome.get()

        self.ormt['text']= user.selectUser(nomeb)

        self.nome.delete(0,END)
        self.nome.insert(INSERT,user.nome)
        ########################
        verif = self.nome.get()
        if verif != '':
            self.gasto1.configure(state ='normal')
            self.gastot1.configure(state ='normal')
        else:
            self.gastot1.delete(0,END)
            self.gasto1.delete(0,END)
            self.gasto1.configure(state ='disabled')
            self.gastot1.configure(state ='disabled')
        ###########################################
        self.salario1.delete(0,END)
        self.salario1.insert(INSERT,user.salariofixo)
        self.gastof1.delete(0,END)
        self.gastof1.insert(INSERT,user.gastofixo)
        self.gastot1.delete(0,END)
        self.gastot1.insert(INSERT,user.gastototal)
        self.gastop1.delete(0,END)
        self.gastop1.insert(INSERT,user.gastoprevisto)





    def attgasto (self):
        user=Usuarios()

        nomeb = self.nome.get()

        a=0
        g1 = float(self.gastot1.get())
        go1 = float(self.gasto1.get())
        a =  g1+go1

        gastototala = a

        self.ormt['text']= user.updateUser(gastototala,nomeb)                     

        self.gastot1.delete(0,END)
        self.gasto1.delete(0,END)
        #busca de novo para retornar o valor
        self.ormt['text']= user.selectUser(nomeb)
        self.gastot1.insert(INSERT,user.gastototal)



    def cadastrar (self):
        user=Usuarios()


        user.nome = self.nome.get()
        user.salariofixo = self.salario1.get()
        user.gastofixo = self.gastof1.get()
        user.gastototal = self.gastof1.get()
        user.gastoprevisto = self.gastop1.get()



        self.ormt['text']= user.insertUser()

        self.nome.delete(0,END)
        self.salario1.delete(0,END)
        self.gastof1.delete(0,END)
        self.gasto1.delete(0,END)
        self.gastot1.delete(0,END)
        self.gastop1.delete(0,END)


    def atualizarmensal (self):
        user=Usuarios()

        nomeb = self.nome.get()

        user.nome = self.nome.get()
        user.salariofixo = self.salario1.get()
        user.gastofixo = self.gastof1.get()
        user.gastototal = self.gastof1.get()
        user.gastoprevisto = self.gastop1.get()

        self.ormt['text']= user.updateattUser(nomeb)

        self.nome.delete(0,END)
        self.nome.insert(INSERT,user.nome)
        self.salario1.delete(0,END)
        self.salario1.insert(INSERT,user.salariofixo)
        self.gastof1.delete(0,END)
        self.gastof1.insert(INSERT,user.gastofixo)
        self.gastot1.delete(0,END)
        self.gastot1.insert(INSERT,user.gastototal)
        self.gastop1.delete(0,END)
        self.gastop1.insert(INSERT,user.gastoprevisto)




root = Tk()
Application(root)
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.title('Controle de Finanças')
root.geometry('400x400')
#root.configure(bg='black')
root.mainloop
```

Ele chama outros dois Códigos "Usuários" "Banco"

Usuários:

```
from Banco import Banco
```

class Usuarios(object):

```
def __init__(self, nomeb="", nome = "", salariofixo = "", gastofixo = "",
             gastototal = "", gastoprevisto = "", gastototala=''):
    self.info = {}
    self.nomeb = nomeb
    self.nome = nome
    self.salariofixo = salariofixo
    self.gastofixo = gastofixo
    self.gastototal = gastototal
    self.gastoprevisto = gastoprevisto
    self.gastototala = gastototala


def insertUser(self):

    banco = Banco()
    try:

        c = banco.conexao.cursor()

        c.execute("insert into usuarios (nome, salariofixo, gastofixo, gastototal, gastoprevisto) values ('"
                    + self.nome + "', '" + self.salariofixo + "', '" + self.gastofixo + "', '" + self.gastototal +
                    "', '" + self.gastoprevisto + "' )")

        banco.conexao.commit()
        c.close()
        return "Conta cadastrado \ncom sucesso!"
    except:
        return "Ocorreu um erro \nna inserção da conta"

def updateUser(self,gastototala,nomeb):

    banco = Banco()
    try:

        c = banco.conexao.cursor()

        c.execute('''UPDATE usuarios SET gastototal = ? WHERE nome = ?''',(gastototala, nomeb))


        banco.conexao.commit()
        c.close()

        return "Conta atualizada \ncom sucesso!"
    except:
        return "Ocorreu um erro \nna alteração da conta"


def updateattUser(self,nomeb):

    banco = Banco()
    try:

        c = banco.conexao.cursor()

        c.execute('''UPDATE usuarios SET salariofixo = ?, gastofixo = ?, gastototal = ?, gastoprevisto = ?
                    WHERE nome = ?''',(self.salariofixo, self.gastofixo, self.gastototal, self.gastoprevisto, nomeb))


        banco.conexao.commit()
        c.close()

        return "Conta atualizada \ncom sucesso!"
    except:
        return "Ocorreu um erro \nna alteração da conta"


def selectUser(self, nomeb):
    banco = Banco()
    try:

        c = banco.conexao.cursor()


        c.execute('select * from usuarios where nome = ?', (nomeb,))
        #c.execute("""select * from usuarios;""") #IMPRIME TODOS OS 
        #for lin in c.fetchall():
            #print(lin)

        for linha in c:#.fetchall():                   
            #print(linha)

            self.nome = linha[0]
            self.salariofixo = linha[1]
            self.gastofixo = linha[2]
            self.gastototal = linha[3]
            self.gastoprevisto = linha[4]

        if self.nome == '':
            return 'Nenhum nome encontrado'

        c.close()

        return "Busca feita \ncom sucesso!"
    except:

        return "Ocorreu um erro \nna busca da conta"
```

Banco:

```
import sqlite3
```

class Banco():

```
def __init__(self):
    self.conexao = sqlite3.connect('bancofinancas.db')
    self.createTable()

def createTable(self):
    c = self.conexao.cursor()

    c.execute("""create table if not exists usuarios (
                 nome text,
                 salariofixo float,
                 gastofixo float,
                 gastototal float,
                 gastoprevisto float)""")
    self.conexao.commit()
    c.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Para quem teve este problema, achei um erro bobo, eu descobri que `Root.mainloop` precisa de '()' para funcionar, ficando `root.mainloop()`, caso achem outro erro no código, pf comentem.